# Override public final method in Java (reflection?!)

Tags: java, android, reflection, overriding, final

I'm getting into a problem, when I was trying to create a custom [LayoutAnimationController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html) for an Android project. It has the method

```
public final Animation getAnimationForView(View v)
```

For my custom LayoutAnimationController, I need to override this method, because each view should get a "unique" animation. 
Is it possible to override public final methods by using reflection or similar techniques, or do you have an alternative idea?

I know that something similar had been discuses in [override java final methods via reflection or other means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748362/override-java-final-methods-via-reflection-or-other-means) but the "solution" which came up there, was pretty specific to the problems of the user and did not completely answer the question of overriding final methods.

Comment: Why do you need to override it in reflection?  Just have a class that implements the interface, and base the uniqueness of the animation on something other than a concrete implementation of the interface

Comment: You might be able to do what you want with the java.util.Proxy class, I am not sure if you will be able to convince it to do what you want though.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no interface for LayoutAnimationController which one could implement - LayoutAnimationController is the base class.


If tried to use java.reflect.Proxy, but I guess I did not really understood what I would have to do, to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `LayoutAnimationController` is not intended to be used like this.

If you would be able to override `getAnimationForView(View v)` with the functionality you want most methods/constructors of `LayoutAnimationController` would make no sense since this class is created for using a single animation (with different delays) on multiple views.

Maybe it is better to look into the source and create you own animation controller based on this information.

Comment: Actually if you look into the code you can see that the LayoutAnimationController is using `mAnimation.clone()` - so any View has it's own instance of animation. Therefore I'm kind of annoyed that this method is public.


It's true that the delays are calculated by the one animation you pass in the constructor, but that would not be a problem for my use case, cause any animation could have the same duration.


Problem with copying the class is, that it has lots of package visibility dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I still feel I should answer as there doesn't seem to be a possible solution using `LayoutAnimationController`.

I ended up overriding `AnimationSet` and just moved the `LayoutAnimationController` functionality to that class. Of course, together with my custom code.

<sub>Finally, I just have to rant about this: this is hardly the first time I ran into some sort of private / final / access denied in your preferred way code in Google's framework. They seem to find it hilarious if they give us programmers a hard time. I understand that `Transformation` only `Animation`s are there for performance, but sometimes we just need something different and disabling us through such childish ways is beyond ridiculous. /rant</sub>